# How to check what pointer is passed to a method?

Tags: objective-c, pointers, methods, call

hope anyone can help me.
I'm trying to figure out what pointer to an object is passed within a call of a method.

So (in the cocos2d environment) it would be something like this:

```
- (void)loadCreature:(CCSprite*)creature
{
    if (/*here I want to check if the pointer is 'blue'*/) NSLog(@"the creature is blue")
    if (/*here I want to check if the pointer is 'red'*/) NSLog(@"the creature is red")
}
```

and the implementation:

```
CCSprite *blue;
CCSprite *red;

[self loadCreature:blue];
[self loadCreature:red];
```

thanks in advance :)

- Yurki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless there is some information buried inside of the blue and red objects that differentiates them, ie:

> [blue setDistingusingInformation:@"This is blue"];
>
> [red setDistingusingInformation:@"This is red"];

And is set before the call to loadCreature, then there would not be any way to tell inside the loadCreature method which CCSprite object was passed to it.

The only alternative would to declare red and blue as global variables and inside loadCreature do a comparison of their pointers to figure out which is which.  But that would be so wrong to do, and if I found out that you were doing this I'd get very very angry :D

Comment: haha, I wouldn't prefer you being angry so I won't do it. But I think you pointed me in the right direction. There seems to be a tag property for an CCSprite, but this doesn't work: blue.tag = 1; NSLog(@"blue.tag = %d", blue.tag); don't know why...

Comment: ah, I can see why now...when the CCSprite is not initialized, you cannot set a tag yet. Too bad because I need to initialize inside the method. Workaround would be to initialized the sprite in the beginning  with an empty picture file, then set the tag and then later inside the method re-initialize with a new picture. Not at all pretty! but it works...